# Error correction code for non-uniform errors on non-binary channel?

Tags: encoding, error-correction

If you ask a person to type in a page full of random hand written 20 digit numbers, I would expect that you would see different errors occur with non uniform frequency (e.g. switching 6 and 5 or 3 and 8 would be more common than 7 and 0). Are there any error correction codes that incorporate that sort of error functions into there construction?

The practical application of this is generating human enterable, error tolerant encodings for things like account numbers or cryptographic keys.

Comment: Not sure about "Error tolerant" but "error detection" is in use at banks since a little bit after paleozoic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit I'm sure you are aware of that

Comment: I'm specifically interested in correction systems, particularly for cases where you can't go back and ask the original source (deposit slips from a drop box for instance).

Comment: I would suspect you don't really need to be error likelihood aware.  The standard ECC should be good enough on its own: overhead really isn't an issue.  However, you do want it to be able to correct bit *insertion* and *deletion*, then you need to look at more advanced ECC schemes like Watermark Codes or Marker Codes.